# TEI element problems

Tags: xml

Using TEI, trying to validate this document but it will just not work for some reason, I have been using the elements and all the guidelines on the TEI website but I just do not understand it whatsoever. Any help is much appreciated. I will comment where the problems are. I have a valid header and namespace so it is all good bar the following problems.

```
<text>
<pb n ="1"/>
<!-- pp/6/122(2)-->
<front>
 <titlePage>
  <castList> <<First problem is here, says it is an invalid starter element, though it is not starting, titlePagee and front are.
    <castItem>
        <role xml:id="b">Belle</role>
        <role xml:id="p">Patty</role>
    </castItem>
  </castList>
 </titlePage>
</front>
</text> <<2nd, telling me it is not complete. It is.

 <text><<3rd, teling me it can not start with tetx. EVen though I have the element TEI surrounding all of this. 
  <body>
<sp> <<This is full of valid speech.
    </sp>
  </body>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to post a complete XML document that fails to validate, so we can check you haven't done anything silly with namespaces, and also to post a specific reference to the schema you are using for validation, so that we are in no doubt what you mean by "TEI" (e.g. which version).

Comment: I dont know the schema myself, but in the examples I have seen, a text element contains a front element then a body element as siblings. The messages you cite appear to indicate that the you should have one text element containing both front and body, rather than having front and body as children of separate text elements.

Answer (score 1):

I found the next problems

1. a minimal valid TEI-doc has one root element `<TEI>`, which has two mandatory children: `<teiHeader>` and `<text>`. In `<text>` there are two possible `<front>`, `<back>` and one mandatory element `<body>` - these for 2nd and 3rd problems
2. the `<titlePage>` [can't contain](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-titlePage.html) `<castList>` without any modifications of the scheme. [Here is an example](http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/DR.html#DRSET), where the `<castList>` element is a part of a `<titlePage>`